# maximum viewport inset can't be larger than frame flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

maximum viewport inset can't be larger than frame flutter WebView
when try open iframe URL in WebView flutter on iOS this issue happens

return SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height+500,
child: WebView(
debuggingEnabled: false,
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
_webViewController = controller;
_webViewController.loadUrl(initial_url);
},
onWebResourceError: (error) {},
navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {

```
        //  print('test'+page.toString());

        if (request.url.contains("https://accept.paymobsolutions.com/api/acceptance/mpgs_secure_callback/get_acs_page?token")) {
            _webViewController.loadUrl(request.url);

          }else   if (request.url.contains("success=true")) {
          if (widget.payment_type == "cart_payment") {
            OrderDone();

          } else if (widget.payment_type == "wallet_payment") {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return Wallet(from_recharge: true);
            }));
          }
        }  else if (request.url.contains("https://ordark.com/")) {

            ToastComponent.showDialog(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).common_payment_cancelled,
                context,
                gravity: Toast.CENTER,
                duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
           // return;
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Please send the code.

Comment: I edit my question and added code above

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this is worked for me.

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
final LoadiFramController _iFramController = Get.put(LoadiFramController());
```

Then in body

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.appColor,
    ),
    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: _iFramController.redirectUrl.value +
          _iFramController.tokenIFram.value,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      javascriptChannels: Set.from([
        JavascriptChannel(
            name: 'done',
            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
              //This is where you receive message from javascript code and handle in Flutter/Dart like here, the message is just being printed
              //in Run/LogCat window of android studio
              print("returnURL" + message.message);
            })
      ]),

      onProgress: (int progress) {
        print('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
      },
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('Page started loading: $url');
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        print('Page finished loading: $url');
        if (url.contains('/failure')) {
          goToFailureScreen();

          //success
        } else if (url.contains('/success')) {
          goToSuccess();
        } else {}
      },
    ),
  ),
```